# How do we use the Bing Ads API to provide Ads on the results page of a Bing search API?

Tags: bing-search, bing-ads-api

We want to create a search engine using the Bing search API. Also, we would like to monetize the search by showing relevant Ads from the Bing Ads API at the top of the search results page (similar to other search engines).

Could someone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get started by filling up the form here: https://www.bing.com/partners. Bing Ads has an API that you can consume later to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your mail. When I try to fill out that form, nothing happens. It doesn't send. I click the submit button and the form just stays there unchanged. I tried many times after cancelling and beginning again.

Comment: Is it necessary to become a Bing Partner in order to serve Bing Ads on the results page of the Bing Search APIs?

Comment: No, you just need to fill out the form at the bottom of the page.

Comment: As I said, I keep trying but it refuses to send after I click the submit button.